# Thick polygons in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

I have a polygon that I want to thicken with thickness `h`. How do I do this?

`FaceForm` is evil and says:

> The directive Thickness was encountered in a context where it is not allowed.

Comment: Closely related: [How to extrude a 3D image from a binary 2D image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6206/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similar to ssch's method, but I though I'd throw in mine, it' just finds the normal of the polygon (The average normal if the polygon isn't planar). It then moves the polygon along this direction to create a top and bottom polygon, and then fill in the sides between these two:

```
normal[a_,b_,c_]:=Normalize@Cross[a-b,c-b]
normal[a___]:=Mean[normal@@@Partition[{a},3,1,1]]

sides[bottom_,top_] :=     
   Polygon[Reverse@Join[#1,Reverse@#2]]&@@@({bottom,top}//Transpose//Partition[#,2,1,1]&)

thicken[val_,t_:0.1]:=val/.Polygon[bottom_,___]:>
 With[{top=(# +t normal@@bottom)&/@bottom},
    {Polygon[Reverse@bottom],
     sides[bottom,top],
     Polygon[top]
    } 
 ]
```

Applying multiple times can lead to fun results:

```
initial = 
Graphics3D[{Arrow@{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}];
NestList[thicken[#, 0.3] &, initial, 2] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Illustration of the function applied multiple times to a simple triangle]

To use this with graphics generated by for instance `Plot3D`, you simply have to use `Normal` to expand out `GraphicsComplex`'s. I also added a slight pattern above (The second part of `Polygon[bottom_,___]`) which makes the code ignore anything in polygon after the points. This is nessesary because some graphics include normals which are not accounted for above:

```
(Normal@Plot3D[Cos[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 2]) // thicken[#, 0.3] &
```

[image: Thicken function applied to output from Plot3D]

Comment: Should be more funny if applicable for `Graphics3D` generated by `Plot3D` etc. :)

Comment: @Silvia The only reason it didnt' before was because Plot3D returns a result using GraphicsComplex, and because the polygons have normals. I've updated with a small change in the pattern so it'll ignore normal and a small example of how to use output form `Plot3D`.

Comment: That is great! I did something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qp92.png) with your function :)

Comment: @Silvia :D [I made one too](http://i.imgur.com/36VKtn4.png)

Comment: @ssch Hmm it looks like a puppy rather than a cow :D

Answer (score 5):

**Layering**:

By creating a bunch of the same polygon at slightly different heights on top of each other the effect can be simulated:

```
(* Same as Table but high is always included*)
Attributes[tableEnsureUpper]=HoldAll;
tableEnsureUpper[expr_, {sym_, low_, high_, step_: 1}] := 
 If[Mod[high - low, step, step] == step,
  Table[expr, {sym, low, high, step}],
  Append[Table[expr, {sym, low, high, step}],Block[{sym=high}, expr]]
  ]
(* Expects 2D Polygon in *)
raisePolygonLayered[p_Polygon, h_: 1] := 
 tableEnsureUpper[
  p /. {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ} :> {a, b, z}, {z, 0, h, 0.2}]
```

[image: layered]

Problems is that the slices are visible from the side unless very many are used.

**Edge Polygon**

The method is based on taking each successive (overlapping) pair of points and creating the corresponding rectangle with height `h`:

```
raisePolygonEdge[p_Polygon, h_: 1] := Module[{
   data = p[[1]],
   pts
   },
  If[Depth[data] == 3, data = {data}];
  pts = Flatten[Partition[Riffle[Most@#, Rest@#], 2] & /@ data, 1];
  Polygon[ Join[{ 
       {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], 0}, {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], h},
       {#[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]], h}, {#[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]], 0}
       } & /@ pts, data /. {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ} :> {a, b, h}]]
  ]
```

[image: edged]

Comment: The edge method is what I used in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13165/5), although it was simpler there since the polygon was regular.

Answer (score 1):

I've already answered something like this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9623), but here's a slightly simplified version you might find useful:

```
(* barycenter of a polygon *)
averagepoints[points_?MatrixQ] :=
        Mean[If[TrueQ[First[points] == Last[points]], Most, Identity][points]]

(* Newell's algorithm for face normals *)
newellNormals[pts_?MatrixQ] := Module[{tp = Transpose[pts]}, Normalize[MapThread[Dot,
              {RotateLeft[ListConvolve[{{-1, 1}}, tp, {-1, -1}]], 
               RotateRight[ListConvolve[{{1, 1}}, tp, {-1, -1}]]}]]]

thickenaux[points_, thick_] := Module[{center = averagepoints[points],
  nrm = newellNormals[points], outerpoints, radialpoints}, 
  outerpoints = Map[TranslationTransform[thick nrm], points];
  radialpoints = MapThread[Join[#1, Reverse[#2]] &,
                           Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] &, {points, outerpoints}]];
  Flatten[{Polygon[Reverse[points]], Polygon /@ radialpoints, Polygon[outerpoints]}]]

ThickenPolygons[shape_, thick_: 0.04] :=
       shape /. Polygon[p_?MatrixQ] :> thickenaux[p, thick]
```

Examples:

```
NestList[ThickenPolygons,
         Graphics3D[Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]], 2] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: jVincent's example]

```
PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron"] // Normal // ThickenPolygons
```

[image: "thickened" tetrahedron]