# Exporting several prisms (or Polyhedrons) to stl (with filled inner space)

Tags: graphics3d, finite-element-method, 3d-printing, stl-format

I want to export hundreds of prisms to stl. And for this stl file to be 3D printable, its inner space must be filled.

I've tried two approaches to solve this problem.
(just two prisms for a brief explanation)

1. The first one is using "Prisms" (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prism.html)
   [image]

As I ultimately want to make several prisms, I can make them with Graphics3D but cannot export them to stl at once.

```
twoprisms = Graphics3D[{Prism[{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}}], Prism[{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 1}, {0, 4, 0}, {2, 4, 0}}]}]
Export["twoprisms.stl", twoprisms]
```

2. The next approach is thickening polygons to prisms ([Thick polygons in Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18196/thick-polygons-in-graphics3d))
   [image]

(This code is from @jVincent, not me)

```
normal[a_, b_, c_] := Normalize@Cross[a - b, c - b]
normal[a___] := Mean[normal @@@ Partition[{a}, 3, 1, 1]]
sides[bottom_, top_] := Polygon[Reverse@Join[#1, Reverse@#2]] & @@@ ({bottom, top} // Transpose // Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] &)
thicken[val_, t_: 0.1] := val /. Polygon[bottom_, ___] :> With[{top = (# + t normal @@ bottom) & /@ bottom}, {Polygon[Reverse@bottom], sides[bottom, top], Polygon[top]}]
initial = Graphics3D[{Polygon[{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 1, 0}}], Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}];
inital2 = thicken[initial, 0.3]
Export["inital.stl", initial]
```

This one can be exported to stl file. But it's hollow. (not 3D printable)

**How can I make several filled prisms to stl file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way try using [`ToElementMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToElementMesh.html):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
twoprisms2 = 
  RegionUnion@{Prism[{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {0, 
       2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}}], 
    Prism[{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 1}, {0, 4, 0}, {2, 
       4, 0}}]};
mr = MeshRegion@
   ToElementMesh[twoprisms2, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity, 
    "MeshOrder" -> 1];
Export["testprism.stl", mr];
```

One possible advantage to the `ToElementMesh` approach is that the model should be watertight since it is used for FEM modeling.

## Extension to multiple prisms

To extend to the two prism case, remove the `Graphics3D` from `initial` so that it may be treated as a region. Then, use the following code:

```
initial = {Polygon[{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 1, 0}}], 
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]};
initial2 = RegionUnion @@ Flatten[thicken[initial, 0.3]];
mr = MeshRegion@
   ToElementMesh[initial2, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity, 
    "MeshOrder" -> 1];
Export["twoprism.stl", mr];
Import["twoprism.stl"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to apply it to mine(with hundreds of Prisms)

Comment: The prisms in my code are combined with Translate and Rotate functions. It seems RegionUnion is not working in this case...

Comment: @dodo_nuna_2nd You need to apply `RegionUnion` to a flattened list of regions.

Comment: Thank you! I think I can make it!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Perhaps we can direct use `BoundaryMeshRegion`

```
Clear["`*"];
bmr1 = BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 1}, {2,
      2}, {1, 2}}, Line[{{1, 2, 4, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 3}}]];
bmr2 = BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0}, {1}}, Point[{{1}, {2}}]];
RegionProduct[bmr1, bmr2];
Export["two.stl", %]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
twoprisms = 
 Region /@ {Prism[{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 
       0}, {2, 2, 0}}], 
    Prism[{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 1}, {0, 4, 0}, {2, 
       4, 0}}]} // RegionUnion

 Export["twoprisms.stl", twoprisms]
```

**first Update**

```
Clear["`*"];
data1 = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 2,
     0}};
data2 = {{1, 2, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 1}, {0, 4, 0}, {2, 4,
     0}};
sets = {Partition[data1, 3], Partition[data2, 3]}
Flatten[Complement[Union @@ sets, Intersection @@ sets], 1] // 
  Prism // Region
Export["newtwoprism.stl", %]
Import["newtwoprism.stl"]
```

[image]

Need to be updated...

Comment: Same error. \ DiscretizeRegion::regpnd: A non-degenerate region is expected at position 1 of~ . Export::type: Region cannot be exported to the STL format.

Comment: Thank you! But looks a little bit difficult to my actual code.