# How to make an octahedron 3-compound with holes?

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

I would like to remove facets from an [octahedron 3-compound](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Octahedron3-Compound.html) - like in the picture below.

[image: octahedron 3-compound with holes]

I tried to combine these two graphics:

```
PolyhedronData["OctahedronThreeCompound"]
```

and

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0], EdgeForm[Thickness[.03]], 
           {PolyhedronData["OctahedronThreeCompound", "Faces"]}}]
```

but I failed - any tips on how to get the desired result?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  `PolyhedronData` gets you the image, and the documentation shows how one can extract vertices.  What is it you want to do and please show what you have tried.

Comment: I was sure this was a duplicate of an older question, but [it's actually not](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9623/484)...

Answer (score 7):

You can't get what you want with `EdgeForm[Thickness[.03]]`, that's not what [`EdgeForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeForm.html) is meant for (that is, styles for the *1-dimensional* edges).

Here is a quick solution based on post-processing:

```
Manipulate[
    Normal[PolyhedronData["OctahedronThreeCompound", "Faces"]] /.
            p : Polygon[__] :> (
                    p /. pts : {{_?NumericQ, _, _}, __} :>
                            Module[{cent, innervtx},
                                cent = Mean[pts];
                                innervtx = {1 - δ, δ}.{#, cent} & /@ pts;
                                Join[pts, pts[[{1}]], innervtx, innervtx[[{1}]]]
                                ]
                    ) // Graphics3D[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Blue], #}] &,
    {{δ, .1}, .01, .99}]
```

[image: hollowed OctahedronThreeCompound]

Comment: so you are working on the next mse logo? :-)

Comment: @chris If one day we have 3D displays and 3D layout web fashion :)

Answer (score 3):

Using Heike's [reimplementation of the old routine `PerforatePolygons[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5891):

```
PerforatePolygons[PolyhedronData["OctahedronThreeCompound"], 3/4]
```

[image: octahedron 3-compound with hollowed-out faces]

---

Now, here is a `Texture[]`-based dirty trick:

```
With[{r = 3/4 (* size of hole *)}, 
     hole = First[ImageData[Image[Graphics[
                  {Polygon[CirclePoints[{1, -π/6}, 3]],
                   {White, Polygon[CirclePoints[{r, -π/6}, 3]]}}, 
                  PlotRangePadding -> None]], Interleaving -> False]]];

tex = Transpose[ConstantArray[1 - hole, 4], {3, 1, 2}];

Graphics3D[Prepend[
           Append[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 1}}] & /@ 
           First[Normal[N[PolyhedronData["OctahedronThreeCompound", "Faces"]]]], 
           Texture[tex]], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Look Ma, holes!]

Comment: The `Texture` based way is brilliant!